# The mower's challenge

Tags: mathematics, strategy, optimization

Weeds have taken over the roads. If mowed, they don't grow back, but unmowed weeds spread at speed 1 along the road. What's the minimum speed of the mower to get rid of all weeds? Roads are connected at each intersection and the mower must move on roads.

[image]

---

To solve this puzzle you have to use the concept of [supertask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supertask).

Closely related to [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115848/catch-the-invisible-and-omniscient-thief), easier but still very challenging!

Comment: Hm, this Witness puzzle might prove to be quite difficult

Comment: From where does the mower start?

Comment: @I'mNobody It doesn't matter.

Comment: @Eric do you have a provably optimal answer?

Comment: @justhalf I havent'. I doubt anyone has. Think of this as a contest!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended games are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6619/69582)

Comment: Voting to keep open because it's not open ended in that there is a minimum, it just may be difficult to find/prove

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** The error in my proof should be fixed, I still claim the same speed.

I have a solution for when the speed is strictly greater than:

> $v_o = \sqrt{5} + 2 = 4.236$
> This may be optimal, I have an idea on how to prove optimality, but I will need some time to pull things together...

Step 1:

> Let's denote $L$ and $R$ the left and right intersection, and $U$, $M$ and $B$ the upper, lower and bottom paths. At any point, let $l_u$ be the length of the grass path starting at $L$ on the upper path. We define similarly $l_m, l_b, r_u, r_m, r_b$. We will describe a position by the vector $(l_u, l_m, l_b, r_u, r_m, r_b)$ (we will never consider a case where some grass is not connected to $L$ or $R$). Let $v>v_o$ be our speed.
> At the start, the position is described by $(3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3)$
> We start at $R$. We follow the path $UB$ and arrive at $L$. The position is now described by the vector $(1.416, 1, 0, 0.708, 1, 0.708)$ (base position)
> ($\frac{6}{v} = 1.416, \frac{3}{v} = 0.708$).
> We zigzag on the paths $U$ and $B$ to clear the path $l_u$. It takes $zig(l_u) = \frac{2l_u}{v-3} = 2.292$ time (See Dr Xorile answer for the formula)
> We move on $M$ for a distance of $a = \frac{(3-r_b)x-\frac{2l_ux}{x-3}}{1+x} = 0.244$ and get back to $L$, then follow the path $UB$ and arrive back at $L$.
> The new value of $l_u$ is given by:
> $l_u = \max(1-a+\frac{6+a}{v}-1, r_b + zig(l_u)+\frac{6+2a}{v}) = \max(1.23, 1.23) = 1.23, \frac{3}{v}$ where $r_b=0.708$ is the value of $r_b$ at the base position.
> The new values of $r_u$, $r_m$, and $r_b$ are the same as before.
> We see that the grass coming in $L$ from $M$ and $B$ is the same, this is due to the choice of $a$.
> The position is now described by $(1.416-\epsilon, 1, 0, 0.708, 1, 0.708)$, where $\epsilon > 0$ is a value due to the fact that $v > v_o$. (if $v=v_o$, we would get $\epsilon=0$ and make no progress).
> Now that $l_u$ is decreased, we can do the same thing. Because $l_u$ is smaller, $zig(l_u)$ will be smaller, and the the new value of $l_u$ will be even smaller. By iterating, $l_u$ will decrease steadily (we can verify that there is no fixed point) until $a$ become greater than one. At this point, we can no longer move on $M$ for a length $a$. We repeat the same sequence a last time but with $a=1$. The last value of $l_u$ is dominated by the grass coming from $M$, and its value is $\frac{7}{v}-1 < 0.652$. We move to step 2.

Step 2:

> We want use a value of $a$ greater than $1$, but walking from $L$ on $M$, after one unit of time, we arrive at $R$. We still have a bit of margin to push the grass further on the path $U$ and $B$ leaving $R$, that we can clear using a zigzag.
> Interestingly, the equations ruling this zigzag are the same that the one for clearing a path of grass, this can be seen by taking this zigzag in reverse: Where we pass, we add grass, but the grass is shrinking instead of expanding. By exchanging the role of grass and non-grass, the problem is similar.
> For recall, clearing a path of length $l$ takes $\frac{2l}{v-3}$. It can easily be shown that clearing two paths of length $l$ and $m$ takes $\frac{2(l+m)}{v-3}$. Here, we want to mow the same amount of grass on both sides of $R$ (when we are at $R$). Let $s$ be that amount. The  time will be $\frac{4s}{v-3}$.
>  The path we follow now is : We do the zigzag at $L$, follow $M$, do the zigzag at $R$, follow $MUB$, and arrive back at $L$. We want to get back the same value for $l_u$.
> Plugin $s$ into the equations, we get that we need $s = \frac{3 + 2x^2 - 7x - 2l_ux}{x(x + 1)}$, and we will converge to $l_u = 0.382$.

Step 3:

> We do the zigzag at $L$, follow $M$, do the zigzag at $R$ follow $MUM$, and arrive back at $L$. This path is $\frac{2}{v}$ shorter than ending the path of Step 2. $l_u-\frac{2}{v}= -0.09$, so we will arrive before the grass reaches $L$!. At this point, it is relatively easy the clear the remaining grass...

Comment: Looking forward to your proof of optimality!

Comment: Hi, I believe your limit is correct, and I have if not proof, a strong argument for it too (and a solution to be worked out ). However I believe you oversee something and it is more complex than you suggest. e.g. after UBMUB I believe the situation is : (1.416,1,0,0.708,1,0.708)

Comment: @Retudin Yes, I thought about it this weekend and there are a few gotchas in my proof, but I had no internet. Yes, after $UBMB$, we are no more advanced than $UB$, so I should fix this, but with the same movement, it will bring the same improvement on the length $l_u$. However, there is a problem when $a$ becomes greater than $1$, and the grass will always reach L. I have some ideas to get further but I need to do the calculus, maybe the speed I indicated is not feasible.

Answer (score 4):

Better solution:

It can be done when the mower is:

> faster than 5.7749 (see update below)

A slower speed than this is definitely still possible.

We'll say the left intersection has $LU$ and $LD$ of grass heading up and down respectively, and the right intersection has $RU$ and $RD$. Suppose the mower goes as speed $m$.

Here's the strategy:

> Step 1: Start at the left intersection and go clockwise around the whole thing. Then the middle section has grass, and $LU,LD,RU,RD=6/m,0,3/m,3/m$.
>  [image: step1]

Then we have a general thing that we'll do once in a while at an intersection.

Step 2:

> Clear $LU=6/m$ and $LD=0$ with a geometric series so that you're ready to head across the grassy middle. This takes $T=2l/(m-3)$ (see calc below). In this case $l=LU=6/m$, so $T=12/(m(m-3))$.
>  [image: step2]

Step 3:

> Head across the middle bar (so it's grass-free). It takes $1/m$. So now $RU=RD=T+4/m = 4/(m-3)$.
>  [image: step3]

Step 4:

> Clear RU and the middle bar. We can use the same formula from Step 2, but with $l=RU=T+4/m=4/(m-3)$. This adds $T_2 = 2l/(m-3)=8/(m-3)^2$.
>  [image: step4]

Step 5:

> Clear RD. It catches the growing grass by the time $RD$ has grown to $(T+4/m)\cdot\frac{m}{m-1}$.
>  [image: step5]

Calc:

> If $RD<=3$ by the end of all of this, then we can mow everything.
>  This would mean that $4m/(m-3)^2=4$ which is a mower speed of 5.7749.

More derivations of the equations if you're interested:

> Clearing a loose end of length $l$ as in step 2, for speed $m$.
>  Suppose it takes time $t_1$ to clear $LU$ and return to the original point. Then the grass will have grown to a maximum of $l+t_1/2$. The mower will have traveled $mt_1/2$. So setting these equal gives $t_1=2l/(m-1)$. They meet at $l\cdot\frac{m}{m-1}$.
>  Meanwhile, the grass will have grown down $LD$ a distance of $t_1$. Clearing this will take $t_2 = 2t_1/(m-1) = r^2l$, where $r=2/(m-1)$.
>  Etc.
>  The time to clear the whole mess (as in step 2) is then:
>  $T = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}t_i = l\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}r^i = lr/(1-r) = 2l/(m-3)$.
>  For step 2, $l=6/m$, so $T = 12/(m(m-3))$.
>  At step 4, $l = 4/m+T = 4/(m-3)$. So $T_2 = 8/(m-3)^2$.
>  So $RD$ is $4/m+T+T_2 = 4/m+12/(m(m-3))+8/(m-3)^2=4(m-1)/(m-3)^2$
>  We catch this by the time it's traveled $m/(m-1)$, which means the grass has grown to $4m/(m-3)^2$.
>  Setting this equal to $3$ gives $m\approx5.7749$ (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=4m%2F%28m-3%29%5E2%3D3)).

It's certainly possible to allow the grass to grow somewhat further than this.

Comment: The last version with illustration is very clear! Nice one.

Comment: Thanks. I'm playing around with some simulations. I actually think the answer is going to be closer to 5 (or maybe equal to 5). But I'm not confident yet.

Comment: Eric just posted a solution with speed 5

Comment: @justhalf Yeah, in fact my strategy is the same as DrXorile's up to the 3rd step. I've updated my answer to show why 5 is definitely suboptimal.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a strategy with speed

> 5

> The red dot is the mower's current position. [image]

---

**Update**

If my calculation is correct, speed

> 4.6428

is also feasible. The plan is a bit too convoluted to be drawn neatly into schematic pictures. But I beilive it's still suboptimal. Maybe someone with a better scheme can improve the bound still further!

Answer (score 3):

My final answer

> $v_o = \sqrt{5} + 2$

With proof of optimality

> [image]

(I deleted my old answers)

Comment: The resolution of the picture is too low. It's difficult to read the captions. By the way, the configuration at step 5 is excatly as that at step 1 except the vertical grass bar along the upper left hand is shorter. So what about repeating steps 2 to 5 again to shorten that bar even further before going on to step 6? That way you can achieve the same result with even lower speed.

Comment: @Eric Step 2 - clearing a bit of grass, makes only sense if there is any. So after 1, not after 5. However, there is definitely room for improvement, e.g. 9 is a smaller but similar T as 6;  Any S for which this is true should be solvable by redoing 6-9 repeatedly.